# Having greater than or less than in hibernate named sql query

Tags: sql, xml, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 3 with named query in the hibernate configuration xml.

The named query originally matched a date with the user entered date, and it worked fine.
But when I changed the equals ('=') to a less than ('<=') it gave me the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not parse mapping document in input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:482)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 57 of document  : The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. Nested exception: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:422)
    ... 107 more
```

This is because the XML parser does not allow '<' or '>' inside the content of tags. But '<' or '>' is necessary to form the <= or >= comparison. Is there an alternate way to represent greater than or less than such that the parser is happy.

NB: I already know we can put the named query as annotation in the code, but I prefer it this way for system consistency.

Sample Named Query:

```
<sql-query name="persons">
    <return alias="person" class="eg.Person"/>
    SELECT person.NAME AS {person.name},
           person.AGE AS {person.age},
           person.SEX AS {person.sex}
    FROM PERSON person
    WHERE person.NAME LIKE :namePattern
    AND trim(person.JOINDATE) <= to_date(:joinDate, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) or `&lt;` to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) `<` in xml.